# Cannot create urls.yaml in order to use urlwatch

Tags: python

I have installed urlwatch and I am trying to do the configuration. I am very, very new to python and the command line. I am having issues with `urlwatch --edit` which returns

```
Parsing failed:
[WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
The file C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\urlwatch\urlwatch\urls.edit.yaml was NOT updated.
```

Checking the specific path, I cannot find the file **urls.edit.yaml**. In its place is **urlwatch.edit.yaml** and in the same folder, **urlwatch.yaml**. Both seem to be identical.

Running `C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\urlwatch\urlwatch>urlwatch --list`, returns

```
You need to create C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\urlwatch\urlwatch\urls.yaml in order to use urlwatch.
Use "urlwatch --edit" to open the file with your editor.
```

So I am moving in circles and not quite understanding what's going on. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To clear any confusion regarding the urlwatch yaml files: There are two main configuration files used by urlwatch. General (non-job-specific) and reporter settings are established within **urlwatch.yaml** [[1](https://urlwatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)]. Jobs themselves are defined within **urls.yaml** [[2](https://urlwatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jobs.html)].

As far as editing goes: `urlwatch --edit` will attempt to create/modify the urls.yaml file using the editor specified by the `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR` environment variables [[3](https://urlwatch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#jobs)]. If neither of these are set, that may be part of your problem, and you may want to try setting one of these. For example, if you would like to edit your configurations using Notepad on Windows, you might set the `EDITOR` environment variable to `notepad` before running the `urlwatch --edit` command, after which a new Notepad instance should pop up for you to enter your job configuration(s) into.

If you're having issues using `--edit`, or finding it cumbersome to mess with environment variables, it may be easier to manually create and populate the file yourself. In your case, it seems your urlwatch configuration should be located within `C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\urlwatch\urlwatch\`. You should be able to create a new file called **urls.yaml** within this folder and edit it yourself using your preferred text editor.